# Adafruit Feather Bluefruit 32u4 get RSSI value within code

Tags: adafruit

I am using an Adafruit Feather Bluefruit 32u4 and I am aware that when you are paired and connected with your phone you can get the RSSI using the command AT+BLEGETRSSI which has to be typed into the serial monitor, but does anyone have any idea how to get the RSSI within the code, like for example stored in a variable or even to check using an if statement if the RSSI value is below a certain number, e.x. -80?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to connect to bluetooth BLE with CoreBluetooth. Use CBManagerDelegate and CBPeripheralDelagate to scan for peripherals. Then later with the CBPeripheral you will have access to the characteristics which contain the RSSI as NSNumber, in decibels(dB)